# Combine a few regular expressions

Tags: javascript, php, regex, regular-language

I have a string that I need to change using regex. So tried a lot of different things, and this is how close I came.
Below are a few examples of what the string can be and what it that case the result should be:

```
case A: "Schoenen US 30 / " should become -> "30"
case B: "Dames US 30 / " should become -> "US 30"
case C: "Dames US w30 / " should become -> "US 30"
case D: "Heren US w30 / L34" should become -> "US 30 / 34"
case E: "Dames US L / " should become -> "US L"
```

So what I need to do is:
1. match the part: "Schoenen US ","Dames " and "Heren " (so including end space).
2. match any "w","W","l" and "L" in the string (need to be removed)
3. match " / " only on the end of string (if it exists)

So what I came up with:

```
case A: "/\b(Dames[ ]|dames[ ]|Heren[ ]|heren[ ]|Schoenen US[ ]|[WwLl]).([0-9][0-9]).(\/ )/g" with substitution "$2"
case B & C: "/\b(Dames[ ]|dames[ ]|Heren[ ]|heren[ ]|Schoenen US[ ]|[WwLl]| \/ )/g" with empty substitution
case D: "/\b(Dames[ ]|dames[ ]|Heren[ ]|heren[ ]|Schoenen US[ ]|[WwLl])/g" with empty substitution
case E: No idea how to do this
```

These regular expressions do what I want (except for the case E ofcourse). But the problem is that I can only use one regex, so I somehow need to combine all 4 of them.
I am a complete beginner when it comes to regex, so if anyone can point me in the right direction would be awesome.

Comment: Test then at [Regex101.com](http://regex101.com/)

Comment: There are some great regex test sites. By using them I came as far as I discribed in my question. The problem is that I have no clue how to combine the different sollutions I could came up with.

Comment: Simplifying will help you see common pattern like `\b(Dames[ ]|dames[ ]|Heren[ ]|heren[ ]|Schoenen US[ ]|.([0-9][0-9]).(\/ )/g` becomes `\b([Dd]ames|[Hh]eren|Schoenen US)[ ][WwLl]([0-9][0-9]).(\/ )/g`

Comment: Just a quick try: https://regex101.com/r/eD6oR2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to merge all cases to single pattern as close as possible

```
 function tr(str) {
   return str.replace(/(?:Schoenen US |\w+ (US ))(?:[wW]?(\d+ \/ )[lL]?(\d+)|[wW]?(\d+) \/ |([lL]) \/)\s*$/, "$1$2$3$4$5");
 }

 console.log(tr("Schoenen US 30 / ")); // 30
 console.log(tr("Dames US 30 / ")); // US 30; 
 console.log(tr("Dames US w30 / ")); //US 30
 console.log(tr("Heren es US w30 / L34")); // US 30 / 34
 console.log(tr("Dames US L / ")); // US L
```

Hope this will help you to understand regex

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for my late response. Thank you very much for your sollution and the even better explanation. I'm currently figuring out the schema.

Answer (score 1):

you can combine regex like this.

```js
var a = 'something';
var b = '[a-z0-9]+';
var c = 'endwiththis$';

var regex = new RegExp(a+b+c) // /something[a-z0-9]+endwiththis$/
```

Another example...

```js
var part1 = '^\\d{1,3}\\s[a-z]+';
var part2 = '\\s .*(?=[m-s]+)';
var part3 = '.something$'

var combined = new RegExp(part1 ,part2,part3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements I come up with a solution that matches everything that should stay into capturing groups and matches everything else but doesn't capture, so the replace is more or less the sum of all captured groups (some of them may and will be empty). I assume that you have strings that shall be converted as a whole and that you don't have to take too much care to validate them.

Finally the regex pattern is:

```
/^(?:dames|heren|schoenen us)\s+([a-z]*\s*)(?:([a-z]+)[\s/]*$|\D*(\d+)(?:[\s/]*$|(\s+\/\s+)\D*(\d+).*$))/i
```

And the replace:

```
$1$2$3$4$5
```

I used case insensitivity to get it a bit shorter, if however you had to take care of `dAmEs` and handle it in another way than `dames`, you would have to remove the `i`-Modifier and use `[Dd]ames`.

You can find a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/eD6oR2/1)

I used `gm`-Modifier to show multiple examples, you don't need to use them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great sollution. I can only mark one answer as accepted, and I could really use nick's explantion, I'm sorry.